# Confuse about Express API to build App server

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

All:

I am pretty new to Express.js and Socket.io, when I try the chat example on Socket.io website, it has some code like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

While on Express.js website, it has some code like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The thing confuse me is:

In socket.io, it uses http Server wrap the app to build the server while in Express, it directly use that app as server, and **both server work**. I wonder **why and what is the diff** when they work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options will create a server, as you saw. The difference is with where the server is created and how to access the server.

With the http module creating the server in the first example, The server is created outside of express. You can access the server from http by passing it to socket.io (or anything else that wants a server).

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
io.on(...);
```

With the express version, Express creates the server. You can still access the server instance with app.listen, which is like require('express')().listen(). Io could get the server instance from express like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(80));
```

### Update:

Internally express calls http.createServer in it's app.listen function:

In the node_modules directory where express is downloaded there is a file called /node_modules/express/lib/application.js.
This is where the listen method is.  When you run var app = require('express')(), app.listen comes from this part of the file:

```
/**
 * Listen for connections.
 *
 * A node `http.Server` is returned, with this
 * application (which is a `Function`) as its
 * callback. If you wish to create both an HTTP
 * and HTTPS server you may do so with the "http"
 * and "https" modules as shown here:
 *
 *    var http = require('http')
 *      , https = require('https')
 *      , express = require('express')
 *      , app = express();
 *
 *    http.createServer(app).listen(80);
 *    https.createServer({ ... }, app).listen(443);
 *
 * @return {http.Server}
 * @api public
 */

app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

(In the comment they suggest a similar method that socket.io uses for creating multiple servers.)

Looking at this it shows how app.listen makes a server. The other app properties (not shown here) are for extra helpers that wouldn't come with http.Server, like app.use, app.configure, and app.render.

Note that http.createServer is only different from http.Server in how it instantiates the object. We can consider them the same thing here.

Comment: Thanks, so in Express.js version example, that app is actually not the server, it only behave like the server with the listen function, while the server return from its listen is actual the server similar to the server created by http module, right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right that app is not the server and app.listen returns a server just like http.createServer. App is an object where one of the methods is a function that returns a server. That method in fact calls http.createServer.

I updated my answer to show how app.listen does this from the express source code. It's just 4 lines of code to create an http server by calling http.createServer.

Comment: No problem. Please mark as best answer if it helped you.